# How can I fetch the content of a post of my wordpress domain from an other domain?

Tags: htaccess

I have my wordpress website, let's say `wp.com`, and an other domain, let's call it `js.com`.

I would like to allow `GET` queries coming from the javascript client code of `js.com` to `wp.com`.

Something like:

File `main.js` hosted under `js.com`:

```
$.get("wp.com/my-post", function(...) {... } )
```

I looked up different information on Google and it seems that I have to edit the `.htaccess` on `wp.com` to enable `js.com`.

I looked at:

- https://www.moxio.com/blog/12/how-to-make-a-cross-domain-request-in-javascript-using-cors
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/activating-cors/
- https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/
- and installed the plugin named `WP Htaccess Editor` on `wp.com`

But now I am not sure what to set up.

The `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` is scaring me. I am worried any website will be able to fetch data from my website instead of only `js.com`.

I am also confused between somewebsite talking about HTTP header vs setting up `.htaccess` vs setting files name vs subdomain.

I just want to open some get request. I don't care about the specific files. I want to be able to receive the HTML of my page on this other domain.

Answer (score 1):

editing the `.htaccess` file on `wp.com` with :

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "https://js.com"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"
```

works